# Converting Bytea to Json

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to analyse Data in a Postgresql-Database which is a Json-Text but stored in a bytea-column. Some of the rows can be converted, but others not. Json without CodePoints inside the text works fine when casting the encoded bytea

```
select encode(myByteaColumn, 'escape')::json -> aJsonProperty as myProp from myTable
```

But for some rows this fails, because there are some Encoded CodePoints inside the string like the German Umlauts (Ä,Ö, etc.),
German words like `Zuständigkeit` are shown as `Zust\303\244ndigkeit` when encoding the bytea like this

```
select encode(myByteaColumn, 'escape') from myTable
```

The Database is set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28a0df52c604d8c308b4894fc24792f0)

[`convert_from()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) works for me:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode('Zuständigkeit', 'escape'),'UTF8')

SELECT convert_from(decode('{"Zuständigkeit":"ABC"}', 'escape'),'UTF8')::jsonb -> 'Zuständigkeit'
```

As a side note, you were getting `\303\244`, because according to this [section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html) in the PostgreSQL documentation, the `encode(data bytea, 'escape')` function:

> converts zero bytes and high-bit-set bytes to octal sequences (`\nnn`) and doubles backslashes.